# MySQL fulltext search - MATCH(column), where column = REPLACE(other_column,'\'','')

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Need to find in table records both e.g. Cristy's Auction and Cristys Auction using fulltext search. I thought better do it - replace apostrophe in search query, also replace it in search data

```
SELECT REPLACE(other_column,'\'','') AS column FROM table
    WHERE MATCH(column) AGAINST(CONVERT('+Cristys +Auction' USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

throws error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'column' in 'where clause', as expected.
Using REPLACE(other_column,''','') directly in MATCH, or HAVING instead WHERE throws errors too...
How can I solve my problem?

Upd. [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=b9693cf6967fb80fc6cb77506e7b8a4d)

Comment: No such error message text in MySQL Error Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=260&p=1&q=%22column+not+defined+in+where+clause%22

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'column' in 'where clause'

Comment: Provide real, complete and unchanged, `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` output.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `table` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `other_column` varchar(70) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '', ......, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ...,
 FULLTEXT KEY `other_column` (`other_column`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT

Comment: Edit the fiddle, reproduce your issue, provide the link. PS. Facts should be added into the question text as updates, not into comments.